# Search for answers to questions by specific user, or vice versa

Tags: support, search

I know of the `user:<user_number>` and `user:me` search operators. However, I'm trying to locate something that I'm pretty sure I had included in an answer to a question posted by a certain user.

Is there any way I can locate or search through all answers given by User X in response to questions by User Y? The reverse might also be helpful some day, i.e. locate or search through all questions by User X to which User Y has provided answers.

Comment: AFAIK, the best option right now is to websearch for it (e.g. `site:superuser.com Karan OtherGuy keyword1 keyword2`), or to use Data.SE if it's an older post (like e.g. [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/120840/search-for-answers-by-a-specific-user-to-questions-by-another-user), use SQL wildcards in the search string, i.e. `%keyword%`; only one keyword allowed).

Comment: Thanks for the SEDE query, @Daniel!